# Ito formula $dY_2(t)=-B_3(t)dB_1(t)-B_1(t)dB_3(t)+2B_2(t)dB_2(t)+dt$.

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

I am working on the Ito formula, that $dY_t=u)t,\omega)dt+v(t,\omega)dB_t$ for suitable choices of $u\in R^n, v\in R^{n\times m}$.

(1) If $Y_t=(t_0+t, B_t)$, $B_t$ is 1-dim Brownian motion. Then I take $g(t,x)=t_0+t+x$, then $Y_t=t_0+t+B_t$. So
$$
dY_t=dt+dB_t
$$

(2) If $Y_t=(B_1(t)+B_2(t)+B_3(t), B_2^2(t)-B_1(t)B_3(t))$, where $(B_1(t), B_2(t), B_3(t))$ is 3-dim BM. Then let $g(t,x_1, x_2, x_3)=(x_1+x_2+x_3, x_2^2-x_1x_3)$.
$$
dY_k=\frac{\partial g_k}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial g_k}{\partial x}dB_t+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial ^2g_k}{\partial x_ix_j}dB_idB_j.
$$

So there are two components on $dY_k$. The first one is $$ dY_1(t)=dB_1(t)+dB_2(t)+dB_3(t)$$
and
$$
dY_2(t)=-B_3(t)dB_1(t)+2B_2(t)dB_2(t)-B_1(t)dB_3(t)-dB_1(t)dB_3(t)+(dB_2(t))^2.
$$
$$
=-B_3(t)dB_1(t)+2B_2(t)dB_2(t)-B_1(t)dB_3(t)-dB_1(t)dB_3(t)+dt
$$

Do these two results correct?

Comment: The first is correct provided $Y_t=t_0+t+B_t$, although it is indeed messy(what is $g$? Is $Y$ one dimensional or two dimensional?) The second is incorrect since for $B_2^2(t)$ there is also second order term $2(dB_2^2(t))=2dt$.

Comment: @MikeG Thanks! I edited it. Can you look again?

Comment: Regarding $Y_2$, neither the equation in the title, nor the last equation in the question look correct. Just calculate $d(B_2^2)$ separately, and ditto $d(B_1B_3)$. You don't need three variables. One and two are enough. Or let me put it this way : the last line looks *almost* correct. What is $dB_1dB_3$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. I used this formula: $
dY_k=\frac{\partial g_k}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial g_k}{\partial x}dB_t+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial ^2g_k}{\partial x_ix_j}dB_idB_j.
$

Comment: there will be $dB_1dB_3$ with coefficient $\partial^2 g/\partial x_1 \partial x_3=-1$, right?

Comment: The derivative is right but in a $3$-dimensional BM $B_1$ and $B_3$ have quadratic covariation zero. A more modern notation for $dB_1dB_3$ is $d\langle B_1,B_3\rangle$ and this is zero.

Comment: @KurtG. So the answer is $=-B_3(t)dB_1(t)+2B_2(t)dB_2(t)-B_1(t)dB_3(t)+dt$?

Comment: @Lucas . Yes it is.